# Grub doesn't show up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 together with Windows 10. However, GRUB won't show up. I tried boot-repair which didn't solve the problem. Then, I also run cmd as admin and used this command
`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`
which created another Windows boot loader in the BIOS boot order. Eventually, I have x2 Windows boot loaders in the BIOS and depending on which one is on top it will either boot Windows or Ubuntu.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you install both systems in UEFI boot mode? Is Windows fast start up off. Is UEFI Secure Boot on? What brand/model system? Some require extra settings. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I solved the problem by re-installing Ubuntu but this time instead of making a new partition from Windows, I chose to do it during the ubuntu installation (install alongside Windows). This solved the problem and GRUB now appears

Answer (score 1):

When booting hold the shift key down when the computer goes through is POST (Power On System Test). That should bring up GRUB.

If your system boots through UEFI then that would be the ESC key.

For permanent change you'll need to edit your /etc/default/grub file -- place a "#" symbol at the start of line GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0.

Save changes and run sudo update-grub to apply changes.

Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2